# Writing a function that alternates plus and minus signs between list indices

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

In a homework set I'm working on, I've come across the following question, which I am having trouble answering in a Python-3 function:

> "Write a function alternate : int list -> int that takes a list of
>   numbers and adds them with alternating sign. For example alternate
>   [1,2,3,4] = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 = -2."

Full disclosure, the question was written with Standard ML in mind but I have been attempting to learn Python and came across the question. I'm imagining it involves some combination of:

splitting the list,

```
if [i] % 2 == 0:
```

and then concatenating the alternate plus and minus signs.

Comment: write down how you would approach, a code that you wrote and failed may be then we can help you out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def alternate(l):
  return sum(l[::2]) - sum(l[1::2])
```

Take the sum of all the even indexed elements and subtract the sum of all the odd indexed elements. Empty lists sum to `0` so it coincidently handles lists of length 0 or 1 without code specifically for those cases.

References:

- [list slice examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-python)
- [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 3):

Not using fancy modules or operators since you are learning Python.

```
>>> mylist = range(2,20,3)
>>> mylist
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
>>> sum(item if i%2 else -1*item for i,item in enumerate(mylist, 1))
-9
>>>
```

How it works?

```
>>> mylist = range(2,20,3)
>>> mylist
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```

`enumerate(mylist, 1)` - returns each item in the list and its index in the list starting from 1

If the index is odd, then add the item. If the index is even add the negative of the item.

```
if i%2:
  return item
else:
  return -1*item
```

Add everything using `sum` bulitin.

```
>>> sum(item if i%2 else -1*item for i,item in enumerate(mylist, 1))
-9
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `operator` module:

```
In [21]: from operator import pos, neg

In [23]: ops = (pos, neg)

In [24]: sum(ops[ind%2](value) for ind, value in enumerate(lst))
Out[24]: -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this already has an accepted answer I felt it would be better to also provide a solution that isn't a one-liner.

```
def alt_sum(lst):
    total = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(lst):
        # checks if current index is odd or even
        # if even then add, if odd then subtract
        if i % 2 == 0:
            total += value
        else:
            total -= value
    return total

>>> alt_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
-2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = range(3, 20, 2)
sum(item * ((-1)**index) for index, item in enumerate(my_list))
```

sum = 11 (result of 3-5+7-9+11-13+15-17+19)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this list comprehension:

```
sum([-e if c%2 else e for c,e in enumerate(yourlistylist)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cycle from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to alternate +/-

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> data = [*range(1, 5)]
>>> sum(i * s for i, s in zip(data, cycle([1, -1])))
-2
```